# Meaning of 2.5D space

Tags: geometry

Human binocular vision is sometimes described as 2.5D or pseudo-3D. I am confused about what exactly this means in terms of geometry.

For example, see this Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D_(visual_perception)

My question is whether 2.5D space is best understood as a 2D projection of 3D objects, or as a 3D space with embedded 2D objects (or as something else)? I hope someone could clarify this for me (and/ or point me to some literature).

Thank you!

Comment: In '2.5D' games this normally means the scene is composed of flat billboards which exist in a 3D space and this simplifies projection . In real life and '2.5D photos' it's more like several plane slices set back at different depths from the viewer.

Comment: "Human binocular vision" is a topic of physiology, psychology, neuroscience, or some combination of these and other sciences. It is a question of what is our perception of the world. I don't think there is literally a $2.5$-dimensional mathematical space that corresponds to it. Even knowing what we do with images in a computer in order to give a sense of "depth" to them is not the same thing as knowing how we perceive that "depth".

Comment: This is the first time I remember seeing a statement specifically using the terms "2.5D" and "pseudo-3D" to describe human binocular vision, so I don't know how "typical" these descriptions are. Many writings seem not to use these terms. A reference or two might help clarify your question.

Comment: I googled "Human binocular vision" and glanced through four links (two enclosed below), didn't see a reference to 2.5D. I second the comment above,that this is unlikely to be a mathematical term (it sounds to me like a popular term that non-mathematicians might be tempted to use). Do you have a reference where it is used, in what context? You say it is "typically described", could you provide a specific example with a reference to back your claim? Here a couple of links where I didn't see "2.5D": http://scecinfo.usc.edu/geowall/stereohow.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_vision

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I have made edits to the question based on your feedback.